# How do i decrement a column value in one list based on column values in another list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an *Employee Prospects** list that consists of many columns, but the two columns that are relevant to my question are: "Made Offer" (values are either yes or no) and "Business Area" (consists of 6 job types). I have another table that lists the number of available positions open by the 6 job types.

Each time the column "Made Offer" equals "yes" I need the number of available positions in the other list to decrement based on the business area. Is this possible to do with using a workflow?

- I am running on a Standard 2013 SharePoint License.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating (6) different columns to correspond to each of the job types. For each column I created a nested IF statement that would compute either a "1" if true or a "0" if false. I then created a workflow that would "do calculation" to compute the (number of remaining spots) minus the count of the job type (either a 1 or a 0). This value was stored and then updated in the recruitment season list.